# Function result undefined when using RequireJS with exported class

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I'm using Typescript, Require, and AMD modules. When I call this function, it returns undefined. If I log the values inside the function, they are all coming back correctly.

If I don't use require([  in the exported class, it won't compile.

Exported class from common.ts file.

```
export class DateHelpers {
    CheckMaxDateRange(fromDate: string, toDate: string, numberOfDays: Number) {
        requirejs(["moment", "alertify"], function (moment, alertify) {
            moment.locale('en');
            var momToDate = moment(toDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
            var momFromDate = moment(fromDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");

            var dateDiff = momToDate.diff(momFromDate, 'days');

            if (dateDiff < 0) {
                alertify.alert("From Date must be before To Date.");
                return false;
            }

            else if (dateDiff > numberOfDays) {
                alertify.alert("Date range cannot be greater than " + numberOfDays + " days.");
                return false;
            }

            else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Calling the function

```
import * as common from "../../Common/Common.js"
let dateHelpers = new common.CheckMaxDateRange();
dateHelpers.CheckMaxDateRange($('#StartDate').val(), $('#EndDate').val(), 365)
```

Where am I going wrong here? All of the exported functions I have used before haven't needed any dependencies.

Comment: You seem to have confused the class name with the method name - it should be `new common.DateHelpers()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `require` with ES6 module syntax. You should `import` the dependencies of your module, and configure your compiler/bundler to support loading of external scripts (possibly by emitting AMD syntax modules if you want to use the require.js library).

Also you shouldn't use `class`es that have no state and just a single method. Write

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import * as alertify from "alertify";

export function checkMaxDateRange(fromDate: string, toDate: string, numberOfDays: Number) {
    moment.locale('en');
    var momToDate = moment(toDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    var momFromDate = moment(fromDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");

    var dateDiff = momToDate.diff(momFromDate, 'days');

    if (dateDiff < 0) {
        alertify.alert("From Date must be before To Date.");
        return false;
    }

    else if (dateDiff > numberOfDays) {
        alertify.alert("Date range cannot be greater than " + numberOfDays + " days.");
        return false;
    }

    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
import * as common from "../../Common/Common.js";

common.checkMaxDateRange($('#StartDate').val(), $('#EndDate').val(), 365)
```

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge and explanation. Do I define "moment" and "alertify" in the config file?

Comment: @stanggt3 Yes, I think you need to tell the typescript compiler about the external modules

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your export is the problem since you can export your class as:

```
export class X {...}
export class Y {...}
```

or

```
class X {...}
class Y {...}
export { X, Y }
```

I think the issue could be on how you are importing your exported class:

```
import { DateHelpers} from "./path_to_class/DateHelpers";
let dateHelpers = new DateHelpers();
```

Check if your dateHelpers variable is undefined or not prior to call the method.
It will help you to figure out where the issue could be.

Comment: It is defined. The return result is the piece that isn't defined. I guess because require is a nested function inside the function that I actually need the value for. It wil actually throw the same error if i bring the function into the .ts file where Im calling it. I added the import statement to the original  post for clarity